# Android media3 exoplayer, Play video from SD card or Raw directory

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using Android new `Media3 Exoplayer` library following [this code-lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#0), but there is no workaround to play video from the res/raw directory. My code for playing from the res/raw directory is

```
    val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.my_video)
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
```

The above code is not working and if I create MediaItem with an `mp4` URL then it is working. Code for `mp4` URL is

```
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(getString(R.string.media_url_mp4))
    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that is working for me.

1. Code for video from HTTP URL.

   ```
   val player: ExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).build()
   val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder().setUri("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4").build()
   binding.videoPlayerMedia3.player = player
   player.addMediaItem(mediaItem)
   player.play()
   ```

2.Code for video from Raw folder.

```
     val videoUri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.test_video_2)
     val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri)
```